# use of declared types in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, known-types

I am using `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Document))]` for every  operation contract in my WCF interface class.I want to avoid using this KnownType.Instead use the DeclaredTypes in web.config. can i get any help on how to configure the DeclaredTypes in Web.config file.

Answer (score 3):

The option to add known types in configuration only applies to data contracts, not to service contracts. If the type of which `Document` derives from is always the same (and not `System.Object`), you can do that by using the config option (more info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731740.aspx)), which would look something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
        <add type="MyNamespace.DocumentBase, MyAssembly, Version=...">
          <knownType type="MyNamespace.Document, MyAssembly, Version=..."/>
        </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
</configuration>
```

If this doesn't apply, then another option would be to pass this option to the `DataContractSerializer` constructor, which you can do by using some behavior which can be applied to the whole service. The post to replace the `DataContractSerializer` with the `NetDataContractSerializer` is a good starting point for you (instead of replacing the serializer, just return another `DataContractSerializer` instance, but always adding `typeof(Document)` to the known types passed to it.